# ImageButtons Remains unchanged when returned to an old view Pager fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imagebutton, android-pageradapter

I have a HomeActivity where I have used ViewPager. There are 2 fragments home1F and home2F that come when swipe right. The HomeActivity has a top bar (used by Linerlayout) where there are 2 imagebuttons. When home1F is in the screen one button is shown(other is invisible) and when home2F is in the screen the other button is shown while the first one becomes invisible. 
But when I run the app I find at first the second button is visible instead of the first one (when there is home1F). When i swipe to home2F nothing happens. When I swipe left to come back to home1F still nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 0:
                    //imagebutton-1 visible
                    //imagebutton-2 invisible
                    return Home1F.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1:
                    //imagebutton-1 invisible
                    //imagebutton-2 visible
                    return Home2F.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");

            default: 
             //imagebutton-1 visible
            //imagebutton-2 invisible
            return Home1F.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");

}}
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
}
```

Comment: add the method used to switch visibility of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Show the imageButton1 and hide the imageButton2  in onCreate of your **Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    imag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imag2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

So when your app launch it will show the first imageButton and hide the second imageButton

Now when you switch between tabs

```
  mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position==0){
                imag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imag2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if(position==1){
                imag1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imag2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> **if you want to switch out the actual fragments that are being displayed, you need to avoid FragmentPagerAdapter and use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.**

using `getItemPosition()` we can update the fragments. In below example have updated fragment titles :

```
 ViewPager pager = /* get my ViewPager */;
// assume this actually has stuff in it
final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
pager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
  public int getCount() {
      return titles.size();
 }

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setTitle(titles.get(position));
    return fragment;
}

public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)item;
    String title = fragment.getTitle();
    int position = titles.indexOf(title);

    if (position >= 0) {
        return position;
    } else {
        return POSITION_NONE;
     }
   }
});
```